# Fixed header overlaps the content below

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, responsive-design

I have the following HTML,

```css
header {
  background: #f6f6f6;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 120px;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 100;
  top: 0;
  padding: 5px 0;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <a href="index.html">
        <img src="images/logo.png" class="img-responsive" alt="">
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
```

As you can see it is a fixed header and I've given it a min-height of 120px. This makes the header overlap the content below and I've prevented that by giving the div that wraps the content a margin-top of 90px.

This works fine on larger layouts but when the layout gets smaller and the image starts re-sizing(due to the .img-responsive class) its height reduces and it results in an empty space below it. I could write a media query and reduce the margin-top but I was wondering if there is some other way to prevent this from happening.

Comment: Welcome to the wonderful world of CSS and fixed positioning. Yes, it's fundamentally broken.  CSS was designed in the days when responsiveness was not a concept.  Responsiveness is something that CSS is only just now beginning to adapt to.and it will be years before the problem is really solved.  There are workarounds and hacks which involve placing the header twice, once fixed and once as part of the scrolling div "behind" the fixed part.

Comment: please don't mind to create a https://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: Try to use another unit for the margin like `%`, `em` or `rem`. With some `@media` to help too.

Comment: @RoySonasish jsfiddle was giving me problems so I created a codepen http://codepen.io/vbcda/pen/QyRMpj. I am again using a margin-top to make the section content visible. It works on wider screens but as soon as the img-responsive class kicks in an empty space is created below it.

Comment: so you have reduce the height of header in responsive?

Comment: @RoySonasish I can do that using a media query but I was wondering if there's a way of doing so without using it?

Answer (score 1):

You can use JS to update the margin based on the header size on page load.

```
$(function() {
    var headHeight = $('header').outerHeight();

    $('.welcome-home').css({'margin-top': headHeight });
});
```

This will get the total height of the `header` element and then apply that size as `margin-top` to `.welcome-home`.

Here's a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/13n7mpbk/
If you try adding to the header, it will automatically increase the margin as needed when the page is loaded.